# Empty record displayed on listbox control MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a two listbox controls on my view. The listbox on the left would contain data while the lisbox on the right wouldnt contain any data. So I am creating an empty list and binding it to the listbox on the right to avoid null exception. Below is the code from my controller

```
 SubscriptionViewModel subscriptionViewModel = new SubscriptionViewModel();
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedExchanges = new SelectList(new[] { "" });
   return View(subscriptionViewModel);
```

Below is the code from my view

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedExchangesIds, new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SelectedExchanges, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "destinationExchanges", name = "destinationExchanges", @style = "width: 250px;height: 144px;", @CssClass = "MyListBox" })
```

Below is the Jquery code that I use to move items from left to right listbox.

```
$('#ShiftExchangesRight').click(function (e) {
    $('#sourceExchanges option:selected').appendTo('#destinationExchanges');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

What happens here is that the item gets added after the blank string. If you see the code above, I am initialising the listbox on the right with an empty string. So there is an empty space seen in my top row of my listbox. How could I get rid of this ?

Comment: Remove the empty string. Client or Server side should be fine.

Comment: I get a null exception as Model.SelectedExchanges contains null value if I dont assign empty string.

Comment: After you removed `new [] {""}`?

Comment: Ahh, I see you are then creating multi select lists from the list and passing in values. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190627/empty-selectlist-in-asp-net-mvc) might be what you need.

Comment: Actually it worked by just doing this    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedExchanges = new SelectList("", "Value", "Text", "");

Comment: Nice, please post your finding as an answer and accept it.